Android version 6.0, is there any way to give voice-activation to the pre-installed Voice-Recorder?
The question
Android version 6.0 ( 2016 smartphone, Marshmallow ), is there any way to give voice-activation to the pre-installed Voice-Recorder ?

Or, is it possible to install a more modern version of the pre-installed Voice-Recorder, one that has  voice-activation ?

Or, maybe by using 'Tasker', but maybe it could only have 'Tasker' open the Voice-Recorder whenever it detects voice, rather than the ideal of leaving the Voice-Recorder   open and record only when there is sound present. I don't know anything at all about 'Tasker', and I have almost no skills, and have never installed anything on my phone, by choice.

Manufacturer = Wiko - Model = Sunny ( 2016 ) - Custom build version = Sunny Marshmallow 6.0 ( 22 ) - There's no other information on the phone or packaging giving more exact details of the model, just 'Sunny', purchased 2016

This phone seems to have either the Google-Assistant or one of the versions of it, which I can only access by keeping the 'Home Button' pressed, or more correctly touched, until it comes up, this would possibly be useful to access the microphone for 'Tasker' to then activate the record on the 'Voice-Recorder' ( the 'Voice-Recorder' APP could just be left open in the background, but not recording, to make a custom made voice-activation functionality quicker in it's response time )



Manufacturers do customize their Android, so there is no single "pre-installed Voice-Recorded", though I doubt there is any with voice activation. [tag:automation] apps or Google Assistant Actions Builder (or similar services) might be a way if the voice recorder app allows users to activate recording hands-free. Otherwise, a manually-recorded "touch automation" might be the only way.

It may help to know which manufacturer/model of device you are using. Be aware that manufacturers could with specific hardware, support wake word otherwise in earlier versions of Android, any third-party app could hold a 'wake lock' allowing custom features but draining battery, resulting in Android 6.0 OS introducing doze mode to prevent that. Unless your device/manufacturer had some voice user customization, it is unlikely.

Manufacturer = Wiko - Model = Sunny ( 2016 ) - Custom build version = Sunny Marshmallow 6.0 ( 22 )  - There's no other information on the phone or packaging giving more exact details of the model, just 'Sunny', purchased 2016

This phone seems to have either the Google-Assistant or one of the versions of it, which I can only access by keeping the 'Home Button' pressed, or more correctly touched, until it comes up, this would possibly be useful to access the microphone for 'Tasker' to then activate the record on the 'Voice-Recorder' ( the 'Voice-Recorder' APP could just be left open in the background, but not recording, to make a custom made voice-activation functionality quicker in it's response time )
